# How to stop using scrollview while operating mpandroid chart in android

Tags: android, xml, scroll, mpandroidchart, android-scrollview

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="KMS"
                android:textColor="@color/oren"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/lcKMS"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp">

            </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart>
       </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I have mpandroid chart inside a scrollview, but its kinda hard to operate zoom the chart because its mixed with scroll function from scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use ScrollView.

Read this for modifying the viewport and "making the chart wider":
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport

It can be displayed when scrolling as well.